How do I tell if two elliptic curves are isogenous?
How do I tell if two elliptic curves are isogenous?
For instance, a paper I'm reading claims $y^2=x^3+1$ and $y^2=x^3-27$ are isogenous over $\mathbb{Q}$ , but how do I figure this out? And how do I come up with the expression/formula for such an isogeny?

Over the rationals? You probably know, but FWIW those 2 curves are in fact isomorphic over ${\mathbb Q}({\sqrt -3})$.

@peterag yes over the rationals. I now edited the question to fix that. Thanks.

This is of course not what you want -but: the part of the Tate conjecture proved by Faltings for abelian varieties [???? and by Serre for elliptic curves, earlier - not sure about this?????] has, as consequence, that one need only verify that the number of points on the two E.Cs mod $p$ coincide for finitely many $p$, to conclude that the curves are isogenous.  See, for instance, thm 3.7, page 142 of Milne's AV notes:  https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/av.html

if only for completeness, see the edit to my answer.

When it comes to elliptic curves, I'm pretty much an if your only tool is a hammer every problem looks like a nail -guy. So this is nowhere close to a good answer. I do describe an explicit isogeny from $E_1:y^2=x^3+1$ to $E_2:y^2=x^3-27$ defined over $\Bbb{Q}$.
The hammer on this occasion is to try a finite subgroup $A$ of $E_1$, form the function field of the quotient $E_1/A$ (using Velu's formula), and hope for the best. If at first you don't succeed, try a different $A$. I still need help from a CAS to make the calculation within the function field manageable. Anyway, this approach is very concrete/computational, and a useful exercise for ignorami like me.
Which $A$ to choose? LMFDB enty of $E_1$ says that its (rational) torsion group is cyclic of order six, with the affine points $(0,\pm1)$, $(-1,0)$ and $(2,\pm3)$, and the entry of $E_2$ tells us that its torsion group is cyclic of order two. This does suggest that the cyclic group of order three
$$A=\{\mathcal{O},(0,1),(0,-1)\}\le E_1(\Bbb{Q})$$
needs to be mapped to the point at infinity, so let's try that (because I'm writing this you can already guess that this is the correct choice).
Denote $Q_1=(0,1)$ and $Q_2=(0,-1)=[-1]Q_1$. Using the addition law on $E_1$ we see that if $P=(x,y)\in E_1$, then
$$
P+Q_1=\left(-\frac{2 (y-1)}{x^2},1-\frac{4 (y-1)}{x^3}\right)
$$
and
$$
P+Q_2=\left(\frac{2 x}{y-1},\frac{-y-3}{y-1}\right).
$$
So if $K_1=\Bbb{Q}(E_1)=\Bbb{Q}(x,y), y^2=x^3+1$ is the function field of $E_1$, there exists a field automorphism $\tau\in Aut(K_1)$ of order three defined by
$$
x\mapsto -\frac{2 (y-1)}{x^2},\qquad y\mapsto 1-\frac{4 (y-1)}{x^3}
$$
transforming the coordinate functions $x,y$ of $P$ to those of $P+Q_1$. Furthermore, as $Q_1+Q_1=Q_2$, we can (another useful check along the way) verify that $\tau^2$ transforms $x$ and $y$ to the coordinate functions of $P+Q_2$:
$$
\tau^2(x)=\frac{2 x}{y-1},\qquad \tau^2(y)=\frac{-y-3}{y-1}.
$$
An extra mental reality check I performed at this point was to observe that as $y\to\infty$, $\tau^2(y)\to-1$. Do your own checks!
The next step calls for identifying the fixed field $\mathrm{Inv}(G)$ of the group of automorphisms $G=\langle\tau\rangle=\{id_{K_1},\tau,\tau^2\}$. The obvious elements of $\mathrm{Inv}(G)$ are
$$
U=x+\tau(x)+\tau^2(x)=\cdots=\frac{4+x^3}{x^2}
$$
and
$$
V=y+\tau(y)+\tau^2(y)=\cdots=\frac{\left(x^3-8\right) \left(x^3-y+1\right)}{x^3 (y-1)}.
$$
It is easy to see that $[K_1:\Bbb{Q}(U,V)]=3$, so Galois theory tells us that
$\Bbb{Q}(U,V)$ is the full subfield of fixed points.
Then comes the piece of CAS-magic. I fired up Mathematica (software dedicated to working with algebraic structures specifically is likely better suited for this), and after reducing higher powers of $y$ using $y^2=x^3+1$ I got the identity
$$
U^3-V^2-27=0.
$$
So it is my lucky day! We have found a copy of $\Bbb{Q}(E_2)$ sitting inside $K_1$, yielding a sought after isogeny $\Phi:E_1\to E_2$,
$$
\Phi(x,y)=(U,V).
$$
Do observe that we knew in advance that the fixed field would be one of some other elliptic curve. The usual method of looking for a linear dependency within $1,U,V,U^2,UV,V^2$ and $U^3$ is guaranteed to give a Weierstrass form (not necessarily short). The lucky part was to arrive at $E_2$ specifically. Admittedly there aren't that many finite subgroups we can readily define over $\Bbb{Q}$.

This raises more questions than it answers:

Is there a general method for finding the correct kernel? With or without the data in LMFDB?
The same question in relation to the answer by Peter A G: Is there a method for turning a quadratic twist into an isogeny?


All the isogenies have finite kernels. And using full $m$-torsion as a kernel won't do anything, because  then the resulting isogeny is just $[m]:E\to E$.

thanks for the detailed explanation of the thought/discovery process behind the solution!

@JyrkiLahtonen See my Addition/Edit at the end of my answer, and, cheers, as they say.

This is hardly a general answer... But actually, in this case, I think it is probably easy to find the isogeny - even if I messed up below.
As in the comments above, the two curves are isomorphic over $K=\mathbb Q({\sqrt -3})$.

Write $\sigma$ for the non-trivial field element of $\text{Gal}(K/{\mathbb Q})$. Write $\zeta= (-1 +\sqrt{-3})/2$, a primitive third root of unity.
Let $\phi:A\to B$ be the $K$-rational isomorphism $(X,Y) = (-3x,3\sqrt {-3}y)$, where $A:y^2= x^3+1$ is the first curve, and $B:Y^2=X^3-27$ the second.
If $\delta\in \text {End}_K(A)$, set $\psi = \phi\circ \delta$. Then, the trace $\alpha =\psi +\psi^\sigma$  is defined over the rationals. So, on condition $\alpha$ is non-zero, it is an isogeny defined over $\mathbb Q$, as desired.

Take $\delta(x,y) =(\zeta x,y)$.
Then, on the cotangent space,
$$\psi^* {dX\over Y} = \delta^* \circ \phi^* {dX \over Y}= \delta^* {-3dx\over 3 \sqrt{-3}y}={-\zeta \over \sqrt{-3}} {dx\over y}.$$
The trace of $\psi^*$ is $-1$, so $\alpha$ is non-zero.
Addition/Edit: More directly, and with the benefit of matching up with Jyrki's answer:
Visibly the isomorphism $\phi$ is ${\mathbb Z}[\delta]$ linear [why I distinguished $\delta$ from $\zeta$ above is best explained from a psychiatrist's couch], and $\phi^\sigma = -\phi$, so:
$$ \alpha = \phi\circ \delta + \phi^\sigma\circ\delta^\sigma=  \phi\circ \delta - \phi\circ\delta^\sigma = \phi\circ (\delta-\delta^\sigma).$$
Hence, if $\alpha(P)=0$, $\delta(P)=\delta^\sigma(P)$.
So either $P=0$, or
$$ (\zeta x, y) = (\zeta^2x,y).$$
That being the case, one has that $x=0$, which implies that $y^2=1$. Therefore, the kernel of $\alpha$ is
$$ \{0,\ (0,1),\ (0,-1)\},$$
and $\alpha$ is, up to isomorphism, Jyrki's 3-isogeny.

Love the addition. Tying the approaches together. I would accept your answer over mine, but that's OP's call to make. An upvote was there already.

@JyrkiLahtonen That's show business!

And thanks for the upvote - I did likewise for yours.
